# UI-Router update history - keep params

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using the new ui-router (1.x). I have two named ui-views with the following config:

```
$stateProvider
.state('parentState', {
                    component: 'parentComp',})
.state('parentState.first', {
views: {
first: { component: 'firstComp'},
}
})
.state('parentState.second', {
views: {
first: { component: 'firstComp'},
second: { component: 'secondComp'},
}
})
```

My HTML looks like this for the two views

```
<div ui-view="first"> </div>
<div ui-view="second"> </div>
```

I am trying to transition from parentState.first to parentState.second while avoiding refreshing the first view.
Currently `$state.go('parentState.second');`